# Can proofs by induction be achieved by defining a recursive function between two recursive objects?

Tags: proof-techniques, recursion, induction

I have two types of objects, X and Y, each are recursive structures, and contain different structures sets of tuples containing sets.. etc. The number of elements in X and Y are is the same.

I need to proof that for every x in X, there is a unique y in Y.

Can this be achieved by defining a bijective function which uses recursion to construct a y from each x?

Could I also achieve this proof using a proof by induction, if so how would I lay this out?

Is proof by induction the same a defining a recursive function between two recursive structures?

Comment: "etc" is not enough to allow clear generalization of your idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you can establish that the function you define is a bijection from $X$ to $Y$, then that constitutes a proof, whatever technique you use, induction or other.

The proposition you wish to prove is essentially the **definition** of *bijection*.

Answer (score 1):

Induction applies to infinite processes. Unless you address a special theoretical problem, I don't think that induction can be of any use. In any case, you would not establish equal values, but equicardinality.